# e4 move part between perpsectives

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

Is there a way I can move an MPart from a perspective to another from inside the code ? I got 2 perspectives and an Open View Handler which should move the view from on perspective to another if its already opened.

Comment: I imagine you can use one of the `move` methods of `EModelService`. I don't use perspectives so I can't provide any details.